# Testing our app in test flight introduces new bugs when using a non developer iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, testflight

We have recently set up our multiplayer app on test flight to do beta testing. When we have someone download the app that is using an iPad that is not registered with the team as a developer iPad, we get new bugs come up and problems we have never seen before. However when we test the game using 2 iPads that are registered on the team as developer iPads, we don't run into these issues or bugs. Any suggestions or recommendations as to why this may be happening?

Comment: This is by far to unspecific to provide any help. What kind of problems are arising? Read/Write to disk? Network? Is an exception thrown? If so what is the message? ...

Comment: We're mainly getting gameplay bugs when we use a non developer iPad. When we use two developer iPads the game runs normally, like it should. My question is, is it possible we are getting these bugs because we are using a non developer iPad with test flight? Is this a known test flight problem or is this just a fluke happening to our game?